# Edit display color in custom app

Tags: rally

I am using the custom app PortfolioDrillDownAPP on my Rally dashboard (https://github.com/RallyCommunity/PortfolioDrilldownApp/blob/master/deploy/App-uncompressed.html)

I only saw displaycolor under gridFieldBlackList in the code and removed it from there to get the column to be select-able in the app.

Is there a way to get the displaycolor field to be editable as well from the app?

Thanks